# Vaadin Layout dont Diaply Buttons

Tags: java, spring, user-interface, layout, vaadin

Hi am usin Vaadin to code an WebApplication.
I use this Vaadin Addon:
https://vaadin.com/directory/component/carousel-addon

My Problem is that my Button layout only display on the 3rd Carousel Slide and i dont know why.

```
private Component crateCarouselSlides(Image iconimage, H1 header, Label infoText) {
    HorizontalLayout buttonLayout = new HorizontalLayout(previousSlideButton,nextSlideButton);
    if(infoText != null){
        VerticalLayout slideLayout = new VerticalLayout(iconimage,header,infoText,buttonLayout);
        slideLayout.setClassName("slideLayout");
        iconimage.setClassName("iconImage");
        return slideLayout;
    }else{
        HorizontalLayout textFields = new HorizontalLayout(new TextField("Name"),new TextField("Playlist"));
        VerticalLayout slideLayout = new VerticalLayout(iconimage,header,textFields,buttonLayout);
        slideLayout.setClassName("slideLayout");
        iconimage.setClassName("iconImage");
        return slideLayout;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your Help. :)

[Slide1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swfNo.jpg)
[Slide3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWMg3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long debugging finally the solution.
A button can only be on one slide at a time. If buttons are added to multiple slides, the button is only displayed on the last one. I did not find out why.
Temporarily I will create a new button for each slide. Not nice to read but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your `Label infoText` takes more vertical space than your `HorizontalLayout textFields` in the second case and therefore the `buttonLayout` is just out of view?

I know that this is no real answer. I tried to add this as comment, but i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: The slides adjust in height. I have nevertheless enlarged the Slides to the whole page. The buttons are still not displayed.